# Maven Artifact download?

Tags: maven, download, artifacts

I'm new to maven world. My organization has maven release process all the artifacts are kept in our maven remote repo, so I want to deliver some specific artifact version to some of our customer. How can I download specific module version?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have a web interface like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) for your internal repo, you can create a standalone `pom.xml`, enter the desired version into the `dependencies` and call `mvn package`.

If you need some sample poms and extra info to get you started, you can look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) and [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

EDIT : I forgot you might expect the artifact to turn up in the same folder as the pom is in. The default maven setting is to download it to a subfolder of `/yourHomeFolder/.m2/repository/`The name of the subfolder is the group Id of the artifact.

EDIT2: here is a sample setup for downloading the jars into the folder of your choice. If you delete the `<outpuDirectory>` setting, the artifact jar will be downloaded into the subfolder `/dependendies`. The execution is bound to the `validate` phase, so just call `mvn validate`

```
<build>
...  
    <plugins>
<!-- Dependency plugin to download the configured dependencies (transitive). -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <execution>
            <execution>
                <id>download-jar</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>put/your/directory/here</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank You Kostja.....I will try what you mention. Is there any way to use mvn dependency:copy-dependencies maven functional for this because I really want download jar file to my specific folder. I have a remote nexus repo